# Deserialize wl_session_values weblogic session

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, weblogic, deserialization

i need to user JDBC persistance for managing server session. and now i need to turn session value (saved in wl_session_values) into a real object. bellow i write my code :

```
try {
String userName = "root";
String password = "****";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String query = "select * from wl_servlet_sessions";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

while(resultSet.next()){
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("wl_id"));

    Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("wl_session_values");
    InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);

    Hashtable<Object, Object> hash = (Hashtable)ois.readObject();
        for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> newHash : hash.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : " + newHash.getKey().toString());
        System.out.println("Value : " + newHash.getValue().toString());
    }
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

but when i try to deserialize the result, but i always get `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720013`.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are private APIs, so I would stay away.

You may solve your problem implementing your [HttpSessionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) like in [this example](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/when-do-i-use-httpsessionlistener/7).

Comment: hi antispam, actually my requirement is far more complex. so i need some work around that i never implement before (that's why i ask this question). i need to get all session data and saved it in static variable that available on application, and i can invalidate it in cluster enviroment. i think this approach can resolve my problem. but well, i think i must try another way.

Comment: You can get session references with HttpSessionEvent.getSession() and then use Session.getAttributeNames(), Session.getAttribute() and Session.invalidate() to get all session data and invalidate in a cluster environment.

Comment: hi anti spam, i write another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755323/invalidate-session-at-all-cluster-weblogic. it may explain better.