# Invalidate Session at all Cluster Weblogic

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, weblogic, invalidation

i try to save user session in a hashmap on every cluster. and when i need to invalidate it, i will take specified session id. and invalidate it where the session created with normal way to invalidate session.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

 public HashMap<String, HttpSession> sessionHolder = new HashMap<String, HttpSession>();

 @Override
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  sessionHolder.put(se.getSession().getId(), se.getSession());
 }

 public void invalidate(String sessionId){
  if(this.sessionHolder.get(sessionId)!= null){
   System.out.println("Invalidate session ID : " + sessionId);
   HttpSession session = sessionHolder.get(sessionId);
   session.invalidate();
  } else {
   System.out.println("Session is not created in this cluster ID : " + sessionId);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  System.out.println("Session " + se.getSession().getId() + " has been destoryed");
  sessionHolder.remove(se.getSession().getId());
 }
}
```

session will perish where invalidate occur. but on other cluster session is still avaliable.

why the session on other cluster is still. and how to also invalidate session on other cluster.

thanks.

Comment: You are speaking about multiple clusters. Do you have inter-cluster replication? (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/failover.html#wp1040345)

Comment: what is inter cluster replication? if you mean that session will be replicated across the cluster, yes it does.

Comment: You are writing about 'the session on other cluster'. How many clusters are there?

Comment: i configure about 2 cluster running on once machine (my laptop actually). i not yet try on other machine. i don't understand why weblogic can't invalidate all of the session on other cluster if i the way like above. but when i invalidate the session on common way, its success (get the session from the http request). any clue?

Comment: I guess you are confusing clusters with servers. Please review your domain configuration (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/overview.html) and check session replication is configured properly (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/failover.html#wp1019188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(it would be good to confirm whether we're talking about servers or clusters - the config.xml for your domain would be a help)

The session object is only managed by WebLogic Server inside the web container - if you create a copy of the session object in a HashMap manually either in another server or another cluster entirely, WebLogic Server won't automatically invalidate the copy of that session object, because it's outside of the web container.

WebLogic Server will automatically, and quite transparently create a replicated copy of HttpSession objects provided that your <session-descriptor> element in your weblogic.xml deployment descriptor has correct settings (replicated_if_clustered for persistent-store-type is recommended)

Doc available here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1071982

It would be good to understand what you're trying to achieve here - cross-cluster replication shouldn't be necessary unless you're talking about a monster application or spanning a wide network segment, although it is supported with WebLogic Server.